# Create a folder subtree Apache Chemistry CMIS

Tags: apache, sharepoint-2013, cmis, apache-chemistry

So the question here is...

Assuming that Sharepoint repository and folders are provided, how would I check that every single folder exists and create folder and subfolders that do not exist.

For example: For folder path `/documents/pdfs/bills/january/house/` if the foder `documents` exist, but the subfolders `/pdfs/bulls/january/house/` do not how would I go ahead and create all those folders under documents folder?

I have to use Apache Chemistry CMIS Library to get this accomplished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since OpenCMIS 1.1 you can use one of the `createPath` methods. See the [OpenCMIS JavaDoc](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/javadoc/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/Session.html#createPath-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Thanks, @florian-müller.